# Bash - iterate over files, exclude directories

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename files in a directory to lowercase. I need to loop through their names. I tried:

```
for i in *;
```

But this iterates over files *and* directories. How do I make it, so that it only iterates through the files?

Comment: A syntax aside: Remove the `$` from `$i` - on (implied) _assignment_, Bash variables mustn't be prefixed with `$`. There's no need for modifying `$IFS` when using globbing.

Comment: Done. IFS is used because some filenames contain spaces.

Comment: Globbing does the right thing even with filenames with embedded spaces (or other shell metacharacters), so there is still no need for `IFS` (there definitely is in _other_ contexts). Apart from that, you're setting `$IFS` to the following characters: "\" and "n" - to actually set it to a _newline_, you must use an ANSI C-quoted string: `IFS=$'\n'`

Comment: You are right. Didn't knew that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test if it is a file, and then do your command.  If it isn't a file, the `&&` will short circuit and the second part will not be executed.

```
for i in *; do [[ -f "$i" ]] && echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: You can also replace the * with $(ls \*) or $(ls foo-\*) to do some more customized iteration

Comment: I prefer not to use external commands where I don't need to. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but ls was made for human readible output, right?

Comment: I recommend using `test` instead of "[[ ]]"

Answer (score 0):

Years after the answer from Doon, I found an (arguably) nicer solution, based on [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/811236/356063). It does not require any test inside the body of the loop:

```
for fn in $(ls -p | grep -v /); do echo $fn; done
```

- `ls -p` will list out contents of the current directory, with `/` appended to directory names
- `grep -v /` will filter the output, removing lines with `/`